# Use Jquery to limit a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use an online database platform called Knack. It's brill, but sometimes if you want to do something they haven't already allowed for, you have to code it up yourself.

I'm already using this code

```
$(document).on("db-view-render.view_321", function (event, view, data) {
  $("input#field_32").keyup(function() { 
    var str=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,"");
    var d1=(str.length<=10)?str.toUpperCase():str.slice(0,11).toUpperCase();    
    $("#field_32").attr("value",d1); 
  });
});
```

to only permit numbers and to limit those numbers to 11. It works well.

But I cannot figure out how to use the same type of code to enforce an 160 character limit (of any type of character).

I've tried other types of code for limiting text fields and they have no effect. it seems to have to be this type of approach.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML as well? Because there is `maxlength` attribute, which you can apply on your `input` directly ([Source](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-maxlength)).

Comment: Regarding your initial workaround (the example within the question), you could also apply `type="number"` on your input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set maximum limit using `maxlength` attribute on input and text field.

You need to set `maxlength` attribute on HTML like this

```
<input maxlength="160" />
```

But if you want to set it using jQuery, you can do it like this

```
$('#input_field_id').attr('maxlength', 160);
```

or

```
$('#input_field_id').attr({ maxlength: 160 });
```

Obviously you can use class instead of id for DOM Selecting.

And in vanilla javascript:

```
document.querySelector('#input_field_id').setAttribute('maxlength', 160);
```

**NOTE:** For input type `number` maxlength attribute won't work.

**For allowing characters what you want:**
There are lots of way to do it in programming. For simple case - you can use javascript `startsWith` and `endsWith` build in function.

```js
let data = "abcskdlfjsxyz";

if(data.startsWith("abc") && data.endsWith("xyz")) {
  // Execute only if your data starts with "abc" and ends with "xyz"
  console.log("condition fullfill");
}
```

For different types of combination like as email input field you should use Regular Expression.

[MDN Docs About Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/text#maxlength) property you can use on an input text. If you don't have access to the HTML, you can add it with Javascript / JQuery.

```js
$('#mytext').attr('maxlength', 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mytext" />
```

Or in pure Javascript

```js
document.querySelector('#mytext').setAttribute('maxlength', 10);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mytext" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas. Much appreciated! I have another slightly more complicated query relating to Knack and Jquery - I'll post it as soon as the system allows me another question (in about half an hour). If you had time to have a look, I'd be much obliged. Sounds like it would be right up your street!

Comment: Chances are i will encounter your new question. However, i can't promise i will answer it. By the way, great job on waiting for a new question rather than just updating this one with a new problem. @daneee

Comment: Thanks @nicolas, new question posted. I realise you can't guarantee to answer or even look at it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to limit the character in the input box.

```
$('input[name="someelement"]').attr('maxlength', 160);
```

after that, you can implement your own regex to allow all type of characters